# checking if character is lower than inputted value

Tags: java

```
if(time1.length() == 3 && time1.substring(1,2) > 5) {
    return;
}
```

So I am trying to make function to quit if time1 length is 3 and 2nd character is higher than 5. I do understand that I can't check if string's character is lower than number. How do I do this then?

My task is too deny times on schedule that are illegal. f.x. 960,970,980,990.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare a `String` with a `int`. You have to convert first the `String` into `int` :

```
if(time1.length() == 3 && Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(1,2))>5){ return;}
```

Note that if the actual substring cannot be converted into  `int`, an exception would be raised.

Comment: Or `time1.charAt(1) - '0'`. Or `Character.digit(time1.charAt(1), 10)`.

Comment: Or time1.charAt(1)>'5'